# Send an email from PHP app in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, laravel-5

When I want to send an email from my app in Laravel 5.2, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 95:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

This is my configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'mymail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'yassirxx'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'
```

Comment: `certificate verify failed` - it looks like a good point to start tracking the bug :) Please, give some more info about the code and configuration so we can track the bug down.

Comment: thanks Adam .. this my configuration MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: mail.php 
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'), 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'), 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587), 'from' => ['address' => mymail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'yassirxx'], 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

Comment: Hi! I'm not an expert in Laravel, I'm just trying to help to improve your question so other users can help you. Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot Adam :D

Comment: Certificate verification is handled by the openssl binary and CA store installation. To verify the certificate you need to look at how that is installed and configured (it may be possible to disable authentication from within your PHP çode but that would be rather silly).